# Twilio make a call and IVR in java

Tags: java, twilio

With twilio i have "make a call" and auto voice is telling some messages. Now i need to add IVR technique there to get request.getParameter("Digit"). But i am confused how to do it and i am very new in twilio.

```
//make a call process
String twiml = "<Response><Say voice='woman' language='ja-jp' speed='0.5'>" + callText + "</Say></Response>";
TwilioRestResponse response;
        try {
        response = client.request("/"+barberConstants.APIVERSION+"/Accounts/"+client.getAccountSid()+"/Calls", "POST", params);
```

Now how to add
TwiMLResponse resp = new TwiMLResponse();
Say say = new Say("Press 1 t accept");
etc
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing the concept that there will be a back and forth "dialog" with your server and Twilio for each step in the call.  It sounds like you are saying that you can initiate a call and deliver a message.  The TwiML you deliver should also include the GATHER request.

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman" language="ja-jp">[Your call text]</Say>
    <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="1" action="YOUR_VOICE_REQUEST_URL">
        <Say voice="woman" language="ja-jp">Press 1 to accept.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Once the other party presses "1", the response will be sent to your server's endpoint as dictated by `action="YOUR_VOICE_REQUEST_URL"` in your GATHER verb.

If you haven't yet, read the docs at this URL for detailed help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

Comment: Thank you. I have done so. But may i please know about the action."If no 'action' is provided, Twilio will by default make a POST request to the current document's URL." i want to get request.getParameter("Digit") in same java class to update database.
No idea about that.

Comment: You are correct about 'action'. If you want to handle the request in the same servlet, check if `request.getParameter("Digits") != null` and proceed from there.  Note: In your posts, you use "Digit". It is "Digits" with an 's'.

Comment: after my question i have posted my function and the return value...Where the problem is?

Comment: Sign into your Twilio account and check your log files. You should see the problem there. Specifically, look at where Twilio is attempting to post the request after you press 1. I suspect that your application error is caused by a bad endpoint. After looking at your code, I again suggest that you put the URL to this servlet in the "action" parameter of the <Gather> verb.

Comment: action="makeRequestServlet.do" like this should be ok???
Warning: 12200 Schema validation warning-----this is showing in account

Comment: Use the entire absolute URL.

Comment: That error means "bad TwiML" basically. https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/12200  It might be safer to use the Twilio SDK instead of building your own XML.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. My problem was with the action. now its ok.